# PhotoImage does not recognize PNG image - Keep getting following error: _tkinter.TclError: couldn't recognize data in image file "MyImage.png"

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I'm currently learning Tkinter, and I wanted to add a PNG image to my Tkinter Canvas object. The code is shown below.

```
window = Tk()
window.title('My Title')

canvas = Canvas(width=200, height=200)
canvas.pack()

img = PhotoImage(file='MyImage.png')
canvas.create_image(100, 100, image=img)

window.mainloop()
```

Seems simple enough, but I keep getting the following error: `_tkinter.TclError: couldn't recognize data in image file "MyImage.png"`

I read that PhotoImage will return this error if you try to read a .jpg file, however, it should work with PNG files. I've also tried out PIL, but that came with a whole bunch of other issues. Any suggestions?

Comment: Are you certain you have a .png file, or could it be some other format that got renamed to .png?

Comment: It's a PNG file. I thought that it may be a problem with this PNG file so I tried it out on some other PNG file I download from Google. Got the same error.

Comment: What version of tkinter are you using? Older versions don't support png.

Comment: Ahh, there lies the problem! I've been using tkinter version 8.5, and according to google, only version 8.6+ supports the png file format.